# Confusion about Differentiability and Distributiontheory

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory, absolute-value

We know that a function $f(x)$ is locally integrable over a finite region $\Omega$ if:
$$\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|\,dx < \infty$$
Some non-differentiable functions fulfill that criteria, for example: $|x|$, $e^{|x|}$, or the step functions.

We also know that every locally integrable function f(x) can create a distribution $F[\phi]$, with $\phi(x)$ being a bump function:
$$F[\phi] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\phi(x)dx$$
Finally we also know the definition of a distributional derivative:
$$F'[\phi] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f'(x)\phi(x)dx$$
But how does one interpret $f'(x)$ if $f$ is not necessarily differentiable?

Let's say $f(x)=|x|$. Even if I use some questionable math and assume $f'(x) = $ sign$(x)$, I still couldn't evaluate the integral because the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus only holds for continuous antiderivatives. So, is $f'(x)$ suggesting that I should split up the integral?
$$(|x|)'[\phi] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(|x|)'\phi(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(-x)'\phi(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}(x)'\phi(x)dx$$

Or is the distributional derivative only defined if $f(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Your definition of the distributional derivative is incorrect for nonsmooth $f$. The definition should be that $g$ is a weak derivative of $f$ if $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g \phi~\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\phi'~\mathrm{d}x~\forall\phi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}).$ You should start with the expressions involving $\phi$, split the integral there, then apply integration by parts so you get something multiplying $\phi$. If $f$ is smooth, your definition is correct, but the general definition is needed here.

Comment: What do you mean by a "finite region $\Omega$"? Do you mean a bounded region, or a region of finite measure?

Comment: Also, your definition of locally integrable is wrong. It should be “for every compact set $K\subset\Omega$, $\int_K|f(x)|\,dx<\infty$”.